# how to send monthly saved report in AWS Cost Explorer

Tags: amazon-web-services, billing, cost-management

I have some saved report in AWS cost explorer, is it possible to automatic send it monthly via email?

Answer (score 4):

Solutions for saved cost explorer reports

- [aws-cost-explorer-report](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cost-explorer-report) - Lambda/SNS code to generate the report (From @Venkatesh answer)

There is **currently no out of the box way** to solve this through AWS UI directly!

Answer (score 1):

From [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/emailed-invoice.html) document:

**Getting an Invoice Emailed to You:**

Follow these steps to have a PDF copy of your monthly invoice sent to the email address associated with your account.

1. Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Billing and Cost Management console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home#/.
2. Choose [Preferences](https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home?#/preferences) on the navigation pane.
3. Select the **Receive PDF Invoice by Email** check box.
4. Choose **Save preferences**.

**Helpful Links:**

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/configurecostallocreport.html
- https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/aws-cost-and-usage-reporting/

**Note:** To receive email for custom reports other than invoice, please refer [this](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cost-explorer-report).

Comment: I already enabled "Receive PDF Invoice by Email". But in "cost explorer" I have some report which filter by tag and I want to receive those report via email monthly, not just an invoice.

Comment: @TienDungTran I've edited answer to include what you've specifically asked

Answer (score 0):

Create a "cost budget", filter by the parameters you are interested in. Now you can and email of the report.